# Creating two lists from one randomly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using pandas to import a lot of data from a CSV file, and once read I format it to contain only numerical data. This then returns a list within a list. Each list then contains around 140k bits of data. `numericalData[][]`.

From this list, I wish to create `Testing` and `Training Data`. For my testing data, I want to have 30% of my read data `numericalData`, so I use this following bit of code;

```
testingAmount = len(numericalData0[0]) * trainingDataPercentage / 100
```

Works a treat. Then, I use numpy to select that amount of data from each column of my imported `numericalData`;

```
testingData.append(np.random.choice(numericalData[x], testingAmount)  )
```

This then returns a sample with 38 columns (running in a loop), where each column has around 49k elements of data randomly selected from my imported `numericalData`.

The issue is, my `trainingData` needs to hold the other 70% of the data, but I'm unsure on how to do this. I've tried to compare each element in my `testingData`, and if both elements aren't equal, then add it to my `trainingData`. This resulted in an error and didn't work. Next, I tried to delete the selected `testingData` from my imported data, and then save that new column to my `trainingData`, alas, that didn't work eiher.

I've only been working with python for the past week so I'm a bit lost on what to try now.

Comment: Are you working with numpy and pandas? You say you have a list of lists.

Comment: My terminology may be a bit off. I have a Pandas DataFrame `pd.read_csv('kddcup-10-nonDuplicate.txt', sep='\t', header=None)`

Comment: You should just use the `sklearn` or some other library to do this, if you want to do stuff like stratified, shuffle splits (when you have imbalanced data, for example). See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-iterators).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for this. Looks like exactly what I'm after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `random.shuffle` and split list after that. For toy example:

```
import random
data = range(1, 11)

random.shuffle(data)

training = data[:5]
testing = data[5:]
```

To get more information, read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Comment: What are these `:5` things?

Comment: @JohnathanBrown it is a `slice`. For example, `a = [1,2,3], a[:2]` gives `[1, 2]` .

Comment: This is essentially what `sklearn` does for it's cross-validation iterators, except it's using `numpy.random.permutation` rather than `random.shuffle` under the hood.

Comment: Ah okay. I can use this but I'll have to shuffle the original data to make sure my `slice` has a uniform selection when comparing the testing and training. Thanks.