# How can I split a list in two unique lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, difference

Hi I have a list as following:
listt = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
15 members.

I want to turn it into 3 lists, I used this code it worked but I want unique lists. this give me 3 lists that have mutual members.

```
import random

listt = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
print(random.sample(listt,5))
print(random.sample(listt,5))
print(random.sample(listt,5))
```

Comment: Do you want the contents of the three lists to be random?  It seems like you do, but that's a critical detail to leave out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating two lists from one randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692100/creating-two-lists-from-one-randomly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from random import shuffle


def randomise():
    listt = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']
    shuffle(listt)
    return listt[:5], listt[5:10], listt[10:]

print(randomise())
```

This will print (for example, since it is random):

```
(['i', 'k', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['d', 'j', 'h', 'n', 'f'], ['e', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'm'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sampling your list three times, which will always give you three independent results where individual members may be selected for more than a single list, you could just shuffle the list *once* and then split it in three parts. That way, you get three random subsets that will not share any items:

```
>>> random.shuffle(listt)
>>> list[0:5]
>>> listt[0:5]
['b', 'a', 'f', 'e', 'h']
>>> listt[5:10]
['c', 'm', 'g', 'j', 'o']
>>> listt[10:15]
['d', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'k']
```

Note that [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) will shuffle the list in place, so the original list is modified. If you don’t want to modify the original list, you should make a copy first.

If your list is larger than the desired result set, then of course you can also sample your list *once* with the combined result size and then split the result accordingly:

```
>>> sample = random.sample(listt, 5 * 3)
>>> sample[0:5]
['h', 'm', 'i', 'k', 'd']
>>> sample[5:10]
['a', 'b', 'o', 'j', 'n']
>>> sample[10:15]
['c', 'l', 'f', 'e', 'g']
```

This solution will also avoid modifying the original list, so you will not need a copy if you want to keep it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't matter to you which items go in each list, then you're better off partitioning the list into thirds:

```
In [23]: L =  ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o']                                                                                                     

In [24]: size = len(L)                                                                                                                                                          

In [25]: L[:size//3]                                                                                                                                                            
Out[25]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

In [26]: L[size//3:2*size//3]                                                                                                                                                   
Out[26]: ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

In [27]: L[2*size//3:]                                                                                                                                                          
Out[27]: ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```

If you want them to have random elements from the original list, you'll just need to shuffle the input first:

```
random.shuffle(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[:]` for slicing *all* members out of the list which basically copies everything into a new object. Alternatively just use `list(<list>)` which copies too:

```
print(random.sample(listt[:],5))
```

In case you want to shuffle only once, store the shuffle result into a variable and copy later:

```
output = random.sample(listt,5)
first = output[:]
second = output[:]
print(first is second, first is output)  # False, False
```

and then the original list can be modified without the `first` or `second` being modified.

For nested lists you might want to use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: This will not work. It will sample a copy of the input three times, independently, which will not curtail the possibility of common elements across the samples

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I'm not sure, did I misunderstand the question? OP wants to have `unique lists. this give me 3 lists that have mutual members.`

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood - I thought that OP wants lists without mutual elements

Comment: Sampling will always create a new list for the output though, so whether you copy the original list or not should not have an effect if you consider OP’s original code where the list isn’t modified.

Comment: @poke I thought so, that's why I'm not quite sure what's the OP's expected result hmmm.