# How to split a list into two random parts

Tags: python, list, random

I have 12 people who i need to divide into 2 different teams. What i need to do is pick random 6 numbers between 0 and 11 for the first team and do the same for the second one with no overlap. What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
import random

A = random.choice([x for x in range(12)])

B = random.choice([x for x in range(12) if x != A])

C = random.choice([x for x in range(12) if (x != A) and (x != B)])

team1 = random.sample(range(0, 12), 6)
team2 = random.sample(range(0, 12), 6)
```

This is what i wrote so far.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are comparing individual elements of a list with a entire list, `if x!=A` is always true.

Comment: Insert random choices into a set until its length is 6, those are Team A the rest are Team B. Or select a random integet in [0, 11], move him to one of the teams and remove that element from the list of remaining people. Do the same but this time in [0, 10].Do this until you have moved 6 in each time, regardless of the order you want to assign people to each team.

Comment: Also: [Creating two lists from one randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42692100/7851470)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `set`s and [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference), like this:

```py
import random

all_players = set(range(12))

team1 =  set(random.sample(all_players, 6))
team2 = all_players - team1

print(team1)
print(team2)
```

Example Output:

```
{1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11}
{0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7}
```

Comment: Pretty elegant solution though I'm not sure what is the advantage of usign a `set` here, a simple list comprehension could be used to filter out the memebers of team A out of team B.

Comment: @adirio Speed is the difference - with 12 elements it is moot - lists might be as fast (and memory wise cheaper) but with f.e. 10**6 elements the list comp would need far longer. Not sure if in-place shuffle without sets would be faster or slower then using sets - but it would be more memory efficient :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner `a - b` (being `a` and `b` sets) has `O(len(a)*len(b))` complexity in the worst case. `[x for x in a if x not in b]` has a `O(len(a)*len(b))` worst case complexity too. The amortized complexity is probably in favor of the set version (`O(len(a))`) but you also have to iterate over `a` and `b` to create the sets. With this said, from a design point of view, using sets for players make all the sense in the world.

Comment: sets: O(1) for check if in set - so far less then O(len(a)*len(b)) - wich though is correct as worst case for lists.

Answer (score 12):

While using sets is cooler, you can as well shuffle the list of 12 players and slice it:

```
import random

all_players = list(range(12))

random.shuffle(all_players)

print(all_players[:6])
print(all_players[6:])
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 10, 11, 0, 2]
[4, 8, 5, 6, 9, 1]
```

Especially if you need to do this multiple times you avoid creating multiple sets/lists over and over, instead you have one 12 element list as datastore.

---

Timings:

```
import random

for l in range(12,30,2):

    def shuffle():
      all_players = list(range(l))
      random.shuffle(all_players)
      return all_players[: l // 2], all_players[l // 2 :]
      
    def sets():
      all_players = set(range(l))
      team1 = set(random.sample(all_players, l//2))
      return team1, all_players - team1

    from timeit import timeit

    print(l, timeit(shuffle, number=10000))
    print(l, timeit(sets, number=10000), "\n")
```

Output:

```
12 0.27789219999999994   # shuffle marginally faster
12 0.2809480000000001    # sets

14 0.3270378999999999    # still less memory but slower
14 0.3056880999999998    # sets faster

[...]

26 0.6052818999999996
26 0.4748621000000002

28 0.6143755999999998
28 0.49672119999999964
```

Comment: You compare every case with 12 players in set, but growing counts in list.

Comment: @mikk thanks,  saw it and fixed :) was just editing - unfortunately same result. sets rule for 14+